# Hide every div (inside ul/li) with CSS selector except first one

Tags: html, css

How to hide with CSS every `<div class="rpwwt-post-excerpt">` in my UL/LI list except first one, but to keep all `<span class="rpwwt-post-title">`

```
<div id="rpwwt-recent-posts-widget-with-thumbnails-2" class="rpwwt-widget">
<h4 class="widget-title penci-border-arrow"><span class="inner-arrow">WIDGET TITLE</span></h4>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="rpwwt-post-title">TITLE #1</span>
                <div class="rpwwt-post-excerpt">POST EXCERPT TO SHOW</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="rpwwt-post-title">TITLE #2</span>
                <div class="rpwwt-post-excerpt">POST EXCERPT TO HIDE</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="rpwwt-post-title">TITLE #3</span>
                <div class="rpwwt-post-excerpt">POST EXCERPT TO HIDE</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="rpwwt-post-title">TITLE #4</span>
                <div class="rpwwt-post-excerpt">POST EXCERPT TO HIDE</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your selector use the `:not(:first-child)` pseudo-class on the ancestor `li` to exclude the first `<li>` in a list from matching the selector - even though the style-rule ultimately affects only `div.rpwwt-post-excerpt` elements.

Like so:

```
li:not(:first-child) div.rpwwt-post-excerpt {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select li is not first-child.

use :not for is not , and use first-child to select first element.

so , ul li:not(:first-child) { display:none; }

Comment: That will hide the entire `<li>` element instead of just the `<div>` inside the `<li>`.